# microsoft-graph api which gives information about user role (is user has administrative role)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for a `microsoft-graph api` which gives information about user role(`is the user administrator?`).
I have user `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All`.
It gives following information

```
{
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 425 555 0109"
    ],
    "displayName": "Adele Vance",
    "givenName": "Adele",
    "jobTitle": "Retail Manager",
    "mail": "AdeleV@contoso1.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "18/2111",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Vance",
    "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso1.onmicrosoft.com",
    "id": "cccccccc-cccc-aaaa-bbbb-dddddddddddd"
}
```

**Update 1:**
Can a single API return an organization's name, it's users with assigned role and access to a particular app/add-in?

If not what are the APIs to get the above information?

How can I determine a user belongs to a work/school account(`alexW@goods-transport.onmicrosoft.com`) or belongs to a personal account(`alexW@hotmail.com`)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user id/memberOf` to get groups and directory roles that the user is a direct member of.

If the account is a general user, there won't be a directoryRole in the result.

If the account has any directoryRole, it will be shown in the result.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization` to get company/domain information. You can find "verifiedDomains" in the response.

The format of IDs of work account and personal account are different.

Example:

Work account: `"id": "3df5295a-e4b1-46fe-8969-e715ccd11057"`

Personal account: `"id": "5d9ee9b4b7ad3bfe"`

Comment: can u please also guide me about getting `company/domain` name, it's users with assign role and access to a particular app.

Comment: @ozil Sorry. I updated my answer yesterday but forgot to tell you. Is it helpful?

Comment: yes, thank you, it was helpful, can you please help **which used o has access to a particular add-in ?**

Comment: @ozil What is the meaning of "which used o"? Is it "which user"? Do you mind opening a new post because it seems to have nothing to do with this post?

Comment: sorry typing mistake
Can a single API return organization's name, it's users with assigned role and **access to a particular app/add-in**?

Comment: @ozil No. I don't think there is a single API to get so much required information for you. You need to get them with several endpoints. For **access to a particular app/add-in**, I don't think we can get it from Microsoft Graph. It should be included in the access token.

Comment: thank you for you support and quick reply. I will check `access token`.